# Indistinguishable object in indistinguishable buckets

Tags: probability

Each of 16 indistinguishable cherries has an equal chance of being placed into one of 4 indistinguishable bowls. Let a equal the probability that one bowl has 3 cherries, another has 5 cherries, and the remaining bowls contain 4 cherries each. Let b denote the probability that all bowls contain 4 cherries each. What is a/b?

Comment: What have you tried? Incidentally, the way you have set up the question, it seems to me that the cherries and bowls are distinguishable at the start, but then you stop distinguishing them when counting at the end.  I think that is a physically sensible approach.

Comment: @Henry My initial line of thought was that since the cherries and bowls are indistinguishable, a = b = 1 / total number of ways to partition 16 into positive integers. So we would get 1. The numerator of a and b are both 1 because there is only one way to partition 16 into 3+5+4+4 and 4+4+4+4.

Comment: I would have thought it is physically more likely you get four cherries in each of the four bowls than get all sixteen in precisely one of them.  Which is why you should treat cherries and bowls as distinguishable at the start even if you stop doing so at the end.

Comment: Easiest approach is to pretend that the cherries and bowls are both distinguishable.  Such a pretense does not alter the computation of the probability, and simplifies the analysis.  For example, compare $\displaystyle ~\binom{16}{5} \times \binom{11}{3}~$ versus $\displaystyle ~\binom{16}{4} \times \binom{12}{4}.~$

Comment: Re my last comment, pretend that the each cherry has a distinct number (1 thru 16) labeled on it, and each bowl has a distinct number (1 thru 4) labeled on it.  These labels do not affect the probability of a specific cherry being placed in one specific bowl, rather than another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to treat it as division into $4$ teams or groups, some of which may get labeled either by composition or by size. Here all are cherries, so labeling can only be by size.

The first team **a** has $3C-5C-4C-4C$ (partly unlabeled)
while the second, **b** has $4C-4C-4C-4C$ (totally unlabeled)

Permutations of the unlabeled (=identical) parts don't count, and need to be removed,

Thus  $Pr (a/b) =\dfrac{\binom{16}3\binom{13}5\binom 84\binom 44 \div 2!}{\binom{16}4\binom{12}4\binom8{4}\binom44\div4!}$